# Adapt datetime field in Yii automatically to right format

Tags: php, validation, date, datetime, yii

I'd like to have a field inside a form, which has a format like dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm. I've done this with the date validator.
But now I have the problem, that the user always have to enter a time, not only the specified day. Is it possible automatically set the time to 00:00 when the user only enters the date?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you might be interested to look at this : http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
    if ( strpos(trim(this->date_field), ' ') !== false ) {
        $this->date_field = sprintf('%s 00:00', $this->date_field);
    }
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```